# SharePoint 2013 User Profile synchronization for SAML claims users through BCS and WCF

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, claims-based-auth

Scenario: User profiles got created when SAML claims user login to SharePoint for the first time.

What i am trying to implement now is the sync of those User profiles from WCF service via BCS. I have created External content type and i am bringing all users info (Firstname, lastname ... etc) via BCS from WCF service. As Users are external and doesnt have a domain account, how can i sync User profiles from WCF service? Does users must have domain accounts for synchronization of User profile from wcf service via BCS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, initial user profile creation must be a "domain user" once created the Profile can be "augmented" from BCS and other external sources. Even if the only thing you get is the SID and User ID, everything else can come from BCS.

Comment: Ok, you mean there is no way to augment user profile from BCS without domain accounts? May i ask if i have other options if domain accounts could not be created for users?

Comment: You could use an alternate form of authentication like Forms Based Auth and pull the user accounts from a database of custom third party. The thing to remember is SharePoint doesn't Authentication, only Authorization. So you need an external AuthN authority.

Comment: All the users are authenticated via third party identity provider called "Thinktecture". I can see that User profile got created when the user login to SharePoint for the first time via identity provider. What i am not able to figure out is how can i synchronize User profiles from identity provider.

Comment: I've never heard of it. I would talk to the vendor about it, maybe hey have a solution.